# Failed to create DB2 datasource in weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: weblogic-10.x, db2-luw

I am trying to create a DB2 Data source in weblogic 10.3.6.But I am getting error "cann't load db2 driver".     Here I am using Oracle's DB2 (type 4) JDBC Driver.   I have provided valid hostname, db2 name and port in connection pool. Also I kept db2jcc4.jar file in $(Domain_Home)/lib folder.                               But I could not able to figure out reason behind failure.                         Your help would be appreciated, thanks in advance..

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to provide more details, including your datasource configuration and the entire exception stack trace. Any particular reason you use "Oracle DB2 JDBC Driver" instead of the IBM driver?

Comment: @ mustaccio: Here I am using IBM Data studio 4.1.0.1. jdk1.6.0_29 & weblogic 10.3.6.                                      And there is no specific reason using Oracle db2 driver.  I have tried IBM Db2 driver as well but getting same error.

Comment: How Can I attach all stack trace ?

Comment: ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <17bcd92341d69861:-4d7b765c:153e8c314e4:-8000-00000000000000ea>  <BEA-240003> <Console encountered the following error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot load driver: weblogic.jdbcx.db2.DB2DataSource at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.DataSourceUtil.testConnection(DataSourceUtil.java:293)at com.bea.console.utils.jdbc.JDBCUtils.testConnection(JDBCUtils.java:734) at com.bea.console.actions.jdbc.datasources.createjdbcdatasource.CreateJDBCDataSource.testConnectionConfiguration(CreateJDBCDataSource.java:474)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to get DB2 datasource in weblogic.
Added db2jcc.jar & db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar file in $(Domain_Home)/lib/" directory. 
Added jar file in CLASSPATH
set CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}${Domain_Home}/lib/db2jcc.jar${Domain_Home}/lib/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar